# greater than not working inside data.table in r

Tags: r, data.table

I have observed the following is happening with my 'temp' data.table:

```
> temp[ Quant==0.95, table(Quant>0.95) ]

TRUE 
270
```

I was expecting the output to be FALSE 270.

Any help? Anybody knows why this is happening?

```
> str(temp)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  27270 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ variable: Factor w/ 270 levels "ABC",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ valor   : num  14.2 113.5 115.8 119.4 126 ...
 $ Quant   : num  0 0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05 0.06 0.07 0.08 0.09 ...
 $ diff    : num  NA 99.33 2.27 3.65 6.56 ...
 $ diffrel : num  NA 701.32 2 3.15 5.5 ...
 $ OUT     : logi  NA TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 - attr(*, "sorted")= chr "variable"
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 


> dput(temp[Quant==0.95][1:10])
list(structure(variable = structure(1:10, .Label = c("ABC1", 
"ABC2", ...), class = "factor"), valor = c(252.646587028526, 
97.5068274054612, 254.414595678155, 247.409223101158, 445.752643124162, 
90.7517305346826, 503.46065187912, 492.167958424324, 470.266144426119, 
98.6691455960533), Quant = c(0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 
0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95), diff = c(0.911415364775934, 1.34678329468818, 
1.36079710720148, 0.713478575642938, 0.427664916600406, 0.197920933441281, 
0.0294742181829406, 0.548231698168934, 3.18522829657502, 0.243689644761076
), diffrel = c(0.36205324776521, 1.40056434784569, 0.537750120680336, 
0.289213977734077, 0.0960343429020674, 0.218567208064285, 0.00585466683249237, 
0.111515398663877, 0.681943574781292, 0.247588027310405), OUT = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
)), .Names = c("variable", "valor", "Quant", "diff", "diffrel", 
"OUT"), sorted = "variable", class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x230a978>)
```

Thanks a lot for any help and/or pointers!

noelia

Comment: No, I haven't used `attach()`. And there isn't a `Quant` object in the environment: `> Quant
Error: object 'Quant' not found`

Comment: ups, now I see: it is about `data.table`

Comment: Please add the output of `dput(temp[Quant==0.95][1:10])` to your question. This could be an example of the floating point numbers [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9508558/1412059).

Comment: `C <- as.data.table(cars); C[speed==13, table(speed>13)]` gives `FALSE 4`

Comment: @Roland I have set the Quant values myself with seq(0,1,0.01), so it shouldn't be a floating point problem.

Comment: @Roland sorry I replied before I read the FAQ you posted... I guess that's exactly the problem...

Comment: `DT <- data.table(Quant = seq(0,1,0.01));
DT[ Quant==0.95, sprintf("%.20f", Quant) ]`

Comment: @Roland That explains... thanks for your help!!